# javascript get/store data from table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to catch the data based on the id's after clicking the button (like store them) in order to use it for inserting needed id's afterwards into the DB. The js written is not working as expected, any ideas what is missing? Thank you for the support.

```js
    

<script>  
  function goo() {
  idprod=$("#idprod").val();
  nprod=$("#nprod").val();
  lastprod=$("#lastprod").val();
  solarprod=$("#solarprod").val();
  locprod=$("#locprod").val()
 }
</script>
```

```html
<form name="goo" method="post"> 
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Lastname</th>
  <th>WK_Solar</th>
  <th>Location</th>
  <th>Save</th>
 </tr>
    <tr> 
  <td id="idprod">P1</td>
  <td id="nprod">James</td>
  <td id="lastprod">Lee</td>
  <td id="solarprod">$1555</td>
  <td id="locprod">Queens</td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="active" value="active"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="goo"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td id="idprod">P2</td>
  <td id="nprod">Marc</td>
  <td id="lastprod">Hoobs</td>
  <td id="solarprod">$955</td>
  <td id="locprod">Bronx</td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="active" value="active"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="goo"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: First, you have multiple elements with the same id.  That's not valid HTML syntax.  Second, what "value" are you trying to store?  Third, td elements display text.  They don't have a value attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You are using `val` which is the attr `Value`. you should use `html()` or `text()` to get the value.

2- You have two rows, you should browse those two rows and get the data from each row

```js
 function goo() {
    var firstRow = $(".test tbody tr").last();
  idprod=firstRow.find("#idprod").html();
  nprod=firstRow.find("#nprod").html();
  lastprod=firstRow.find("#lastprod").html();
  solarprod=firstRow.find("#solarprod").html();
  locprod=firstRow.find("#locprod").html()
    
    console.log(idprod)
 }
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
   goo();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="goo" method="post"> 
<table border="1" class="test">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Lastname</th>
  <th>WK_Solar</th>
  <th>Location</th>
  <th>Save</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
    <tr> 
  <td id="idprod">P1</td>
  <td id="nprod">James</td>
  <td id="lastprod">Lee</td>
  <td id="solarprod">$1555</td>
  <td id="locprod">Queens</td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="active" value="active"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="goo"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td id="idprod">P2</td>
  <td id="nprod">Marc</td>
  <td id="lastprod">Hoobs</td>
  <td id="solarprod">$955</td>
  <td id="locprod">Bronx</td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="active" value="active"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="goo"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
```